# How to run a process with high privileges using remote debugging

Tags: ida, debugging, remote

I am using remote debugging with IDA. The target and host machine are Windows.
I can run the process on the remote machine and debug it with IDA using remote debugging but I need that the process will run with high privileges.
In IDA I only have the option start the process (`F9` or the green play button) but it doesn't run it with high privileges.

How can I do it?

I searched also in the options of the debugger and didn't see such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the debug server as admin, this should be enough.

Comment: Yes, but I still have weird behaviour. I checked on Procmon and when I run it with privileges local on the system it call `RegSetValue` for some keys while with the remove debugging it doesn't happen although now it runs with `High` integrity. Oh, maybe it identify when I use the debugger.. I will need to check it.